# Could a Yubikey Provide the Optional Secret to OPAQUE When Using Argon2?

Tags: argon2, pake, smartcard

I've been studying the OPAQUE protocol, and I like it (so far).

The [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-opaque-08.txt) suggests using Argon2 as the Key-Stretching Function. Argon2 can take an optional "Secret value" ([2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/master/argon2-specs.pdf), page 5).

I had the idea that that secret value could be provided by a Yubikey, so that the resulting OPAQUE protocol could use "something you have" (Yubikey) and "something you know" (password).

Is this possible? Is it even a good idea?

Comment: You could of course make the argument that a Yubi could be impersonated/synthesised unless it has PUF qualities. So you wouldn't have 2F authentication.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I thought it would be "good enough."